# Deterministic pseudorandom bytes for crypto

Tags: go, random, cryptography

Is there a way to generate random bytes for crypto in Go deterministically, from a high-entropy seed?

I found [crypto/rand](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/), which is safe for crypto but not deterministic.

I found [math/rand](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/), which can be initialized with a seed, but is not safe for crypto.

I found [x/crypto/chacha20](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20), and I was wondering if it would be safe to use [XORKeyStream](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20#Cipher.XORKeyStream) with a `src` value of 1s. The seed would be the key and nonce, which could be generated with crypto/rand.

**Edit**

As an example of what I'm after, [cryptonite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.27/docs/Crypto-Random.html), which is the main Haskell crypto library, has a function `drgNewSeed` that you can use to make a random generator from a seed.

Comment: My earlier comment may be wrong. This might help: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-number-generator-to-be-cryptographically-secure

Comment: Isn't "deterministic" and "cryptographically secure" contradictory? If you need this for testing purposes, use an interface and mock it in tests.

Comment: I'm open to correction, but I think stream ciphers like ChaCha20 work by producing a huge amount of high-quality random output from a small input, and will always produce the same output given the same input.

Comment: It would help if you could give a definitive example of what you're describing in another language or application. It seems that what you're describing doesn't exist in the standard library, and you'll probably need the right nomenclature to find a third party library (if there is one)

Comment: The output of many cryptographic RBGs is unpredictable only when their internal state is kept secret. Stream ciphers are real. There is nothing contradictory or unreasonable about this question.

Comment: @erickson "Deterministic random" seems pretty contradictory. But perhaps it's just imprecise language?

Comment: @Flimzy It might be jargon specific to the domain, but the phrase is accepted, and improves precision of literature search results. For example, see [NIST's Recommendation for Random Number Generation Using *Deterministic Random* Bit Generators.](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final)

Comment: @erickson: TIL. Mind blown.

Comment: Reading this question, and comments, has been educational for me. But now I'm left with the impression that this is essentially a resource request. Am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @Flimzy I was hoping it would be a standard kind of SO question. Q: "how can I do X?"; A: "here's two lines of code that do X".

Comment: I can't really imagine an answer other than "Use [some specific package]". But I'm not familiar with this problem domain, so my imagination may be severely limited.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a [Key Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) that you really want? Without more details nobody can really say for sure if your proposed usage is "safe for crypto".

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk What I'm after is a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), rather than a KDF, though there do seem to be similarities between them. I know KDFs are often used for key stretching, and need to be slow for that, whereas CSPRNGs should be as fast as possible.

Comment: KDFs don't have to be slow. The category you're thinking of is a PBKDF (password-based KDF). HKDF (HMAC KDF) is a kind of fast KDF. But I agree that KDFs generally aren't what you're looking for. Your question exactly describes a CSPRNG. I'm not sure why there's been so much objection to it. All PRNGs (including CSPRNGs) are deterministic. That's what the "P" is all about. Generating a random, but deterministic, stream of values is how half of encryption systems work. (The others generate a random, but deterministic, stream of permutations.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, XORKeyStream would be fine for this, and is a good design for a CSPRNG. The entire point of a stream cipher is that it generates a stream of "effectively random" values given a seed (the key and the IV). Those stream values are then XORed with the plaintext. "Effectively random" in this context means that there is no "efficient algorithm" (one that runs in polynomial time) that can distinguish this sequence from a "truly random" sequence. And that's what you want.

There's no need to pull in ChaCha20, though. You can use a built-in cipher like AES. Any block cipher can be converted into a stream cipher using one of several modes, such as CTR, OFB, or CFB. The differences between these modes don't really matter for this problem.

```
// Defining some seed, split across a "key" and an "iv"
key, _ := hex.DecodeString("6368616e676520746869732070617373")
iv, _ := hex.DecodeString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef")

// We can turn a block cipher into a stream cipher, and AES is handy
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Convert block cipher into a stream cipher using a streaming mode like CTR
// OFB or CFB would work, too
stream := cipher.NewCTR(block, iv)

for x := 0; x < 10; x++ {
        // Create a fixed value of the size you want
    value := []byte{0}
    
    // Transform it to a random value
    stream.XORKeyStream(value, value)

    fmt.Printf("%d\n", value)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T77nDc_g_bL)

There are several other approaches you can use here. You can use a secure hash like SHA-256 to hash a counter (pick a random 128-bit number and keep incrementing it, hashing each value). Or you could hash the previous result (I have heard a little bit of controversy over whether it's possible for repeated hashes to impact the security of the hash. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/any-weakness-when-performing-sha-256-repeatedly and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15481/will-repeated-rounds-of-sha-512-provide-random-numbers/15488 for more.)

You can also use a block cipher to do the same thing, by encrypting a counter or the previous output. That's pretty close to what the stream cipher modes are doing. You can just do it by hand, too.

If you want to dig into this, you might search for ["csprng stream cipher"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=csprng+stream+cipher) at crypto.stackexchange.com. That's a better place to ask for crypto advice, but IMO this is a programming-specific question, so did belong here.

Answer (score 3):

In random number generation, first, limited randomness **harvested** from the computer's **unpredictable elements**. This physical randomness then cleaned from possible biases, like hashing, then the resulting smaller **true randomness** is stretched into many by using a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG).

PRNG's are deterministic which means that if the initial value (the initial true randomness - the seed) is known then the rest will be known.  **Keep this always secret**!

We are not lost, the important design goal of the PRNGs is that the outputs should not be predictable from any other output. This is a strong requirement indicating that it should be impossible to learn the internal states only by looking at the outputs.

Go's [crypto/rand](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) uses the underlying system functionalities to get the physical randomness.

> On Linux and FreeBSD, Reader uses getrandom(2) if available, /dev/urandom otherwise. On OpenBSD, Reader uses getentropy(2). On other Unix-like systems, Reader reads from /dev/urandom. On Windows systems, Reader uses the CryptGenRandom API. On Wasm, Reader uses the Web Crypto API.

Then one can use possible good Deterministic RBG like the Hash-DRGB, HMAC-DRGB, and CTR-DRGB as defined in [NIST 800-90](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf)

You can use the `x/crypto/chacha20` to generate the long deterministic random sequence. **Keep the key and nonce fixed and secret** then you will have a deterministic DRGB. It is very fast, and seekable, too.